# how to load class from jar inside equinox server side application in jboss 7

Tags: servlets, jboss, classloader, equinox, bridge

I'm face a problem since few days and I can't get solution. below is my app structure:

I have ejbapp.jar inside MyearDeployedOnJboss7.ear at the same level of equinox-server-side-app.war (built using warproduct) and I want to load class from MyJarToLaoadForEjbapp.jar which is in iModernizeWebClient_1.0.0.jar which is in plugins folder of equinox-server-side-app.war (I want show image of app structure but I cannot send image because forum rules need 10 score to be able to do that)

My question is how to allow ejbapp.jar load classes from "MyJarToLaoadForEjbapp.jar" inside MyWebClient_1.0.0.jar's plugin folder which is in the equinox-server-side-app.war.

I think using servletbridge classloader but no idea how to use it.

in my launch.ini I've:

```
osgi.*=@null org.osgi.*=@null eclipse.*=@null osgi.parentClassloader=app osgi.contextClassLoaderParent=app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my proble using Servlet HttpServiceTracker from the OSGI spec. how to do it  : write HttpServiceTracker liket that :

```
public class HttpServiceTracker extends ServiceTracker {

private static final Logger logger = Logger
        .getLogger(HttpServiceTracker.class.getName());


public HttpServiceTracker(BundleContext context) {
    super(context, HttpService.class.getName(), null);
}

public Object addingService(ServiceReference reference) {
    HttpService httpService = (HttpService) context.getService(reference);
    logger.info("default context path : "
            + org.eclipse.rap.ui.internal.servlet.HttpServiceTracker.ID_HTTP_CONTEXT);
    try {
        logger.info("will register servlet ");
        httpService.registerServlet("/programLauncherServlet",
                new ProgramLauncherServlet(), null, null);
        logger.info("servlet has been registred with http context ");
        // httpService.registerResources( "/", "/html", null );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        logger.info("The alias '/programLauncherServlet' is already in use");
    }

    return httpService;
}

public void removedService(ServiceReference reference, Object service) {
    logger.info("will unregister servlet ");
    HttpService httpService = (HttpService) service;
    httpService.unregister("/programLauncher");
    super.removedService(reference, service);
    logger.info("servlet has been unregistred");
}
```

in your plugin activator class at method start :

```
@Override
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    super.start(context);
    Activator.plugin = this;

    BundleContext osgiContext = BundleReference.class
            .cast(AnyClassOfYourProject.class.getClassLoader()).getBundle()
            .getBundleContext();
    serviceTracker = new HttpServiceTracker(osgiContext);
    serviceTracker.open();
    LOGGER.info("servlet published !!");
    LOGGER.info("Bundle started.");
}
```

and for unregister the servlet at the stop method :

```
public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    Activator.plugin = null;
    serviceTracker.close();
    serviceTracker = null;
    LOGGER.info("servlet unregistered from context !!");
    super.stop(context);
}
```

that's all. your servlet is accessible outside your eclipse bundle and you can call methods inside the bundle.